# Error initializing array size using const static variable of class template

Tags: c++, arrays, size, static-variables, template-classes

```
template<typename T, typename C = vector<T>>
class stack{
    ...
    friend class stack_array;
};

template<typename T, typename C = vector<T>, typename K = stack<T,C>>
class stack_array{
     ...
     static const size_t max_elem;
     array<K, max_elem> store;
     ...
};

template<typename T, typename C = vector<T>, typename K = stack<T,C>>
const size_t stack_array<T,C,K>::max_elem = 10;
```

I get the following compilation error for the above:

```
error: the value of ‘stack_array<T, C, K>::max_elem’ is not usable in a constant expression
array<K, max_elem> store;
                ^
note: ‘stack_array<T, C, K>::max_elem’ was not initialized with a constant expression
static const size_t max_elem;
```

I presume this error occurs since the static const variable `max_elem` is initialized after the template class definition. Is this understanding correct?
Is there a way to resolve this error without necessarily changing the current usage of `max_elem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I 'd say to initialize the static member right in place.

```
static const size_t max_elem = 10;
```

More [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static).

> Constant static members If a static data member of integral or
>   enumeration type is declared const (and not volatile), it can be
>   initialized with an initializer in which every expression is a
>   constant expression, right inside the class definition:

```
struct X {
     const static int n = 1;
     const static int m{2}; // since C++11
     const static int k; }; 

     const int X::k = 3; // Only this needs to be defined
```